# Angular Routing with "?" before hash

Tags: angular, angular4-router

We need to insert a hash in the url with a question mark before. Just like

localhost:4200/?***HASHCODE***

and read only the hash.

Right now is reading it without the question mark, but when we put it before the hash, it doest not work.

How can we configure de routing properly to reach this requirement?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You mean something like 'localhost:4200/?key=value'?

Comment: I mean localhost:4200/?<HASHCODE>

Comment: Why wouldn't you use Query Parameters like @ArmenVardanyan suggested. Its supported natively within Angular.

Comment: So you want to just pass a param to your route, right?

Comment: I'ts not my decision, it's business requiremente for some reason. Is it possible?

Comment: You should object, respectfully of course, the "business requirement". What you are trying to do isn't supported in standard URL definition. You would either need to make it part of the route, or use a query parameter. Those are the only two ways to pass data using a URL that are supported. Any deviation and you are likely asking for trouble.  There is a "3rd" way, but it's bookmarking, and not really a way to pass data, using an actual hash (#) symbol.

Answer (score 1):

What you try to accomplish is impossible and incorrect. Query Parameters are a part of standard of using URL for transferring data, in the first place, and those parameters are **key-value**. In Angular you can do the following:

```
{path: ':hashcode', component: MyComponent} // your route
// in MyComponent
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}
ngOnInit() {this.route.params.subscribe(params => // do something with params)}
```

Or this way:

```
{path: '', component: MyComponent // you don't need to define query parameters inside the route definition}
// same code inside the component, but just subscribe to queryParams Observable instead of params
```

This "business requirement" is weird, unnecessary and useless. You need to confront it.